# After parenting model to rig mesh stretches to 3D cursor

Tags: rigging

[image]

When I parent rig and model with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weight* the model is going to 3D cursor. Why?

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't provide any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently blender sets pivots for bones to the currently set transform pivot in the editor during parenting. It is in small panel int the top ( the one with options : bounding box center, individual origin, median points and 3dcursor ). You must have left 3d cursor as pivot when parenting. Set it back to default